# Как извлечь логин и пароль с URL

Tags: php, url, rest, auth

Делаю свой REST API для Android приложения.

Хочу, что бы логин и токен передавались на сервер через url следующим образом:
login:token@mysite.com/index.php

Спецификация URL это позволяет:
[image: https://habrastorage.org/files/373/2b3/3fd/3732b33fd43043049c18e3c108bc9d1a.jpg]

Вопрос в следующем, как, куда передаются эти данные (login:token) и, что самое главное, как их можно получить в скрипте index.php?

Что сделал для решения:
 1. Перерыл пол гугла
 2. Отдампил все суперглобальные переменные PHP ($_SERVER, $_POST и тп.)

Comment: Тут ключевой элемент `SCHEME`, в зависимости от него вы можете так делать или нет. В чем разница между тем что вы хотите и например передать логин и пасс через `_GET`? только внешним видом, клиент все равно не видит, какая разница-то...

Comment: С Rest и вообще с http внутренностями познакомился всего несколько дней назад. С топиков на разных форумах и постов понял, что Rest использует методы запросов (get, post и тд) для идентификации действия, которого я хочу совершить на стороне сервера. С этого сделал вывод, что если буду отправлять,например, методом DELETE, то не смогу отправить вместе с ним данные о пользователе. Если вы хорошо разбираетесь в этом, прошу подтолкнуть меня в нужную сторону для размышлений. Спасибо! :)

Comment: Почитайте про Basic Auth и его реализацию на php

Answer (score 1):

Секрет тут в том, что *URL на сервер не передаётся*. Это всего лишь более-менее удобный способ упаковать разнородные параметры в одну строку. Которую клиент разбирает на части, и использует для соединения с сервером. Причем некоторые параметры (например fragment) и вовсе никогда на сервер не попадают.

Чтобы получить логин и пароль из этой строки, сервер должен инициировать HTTP Basic Authentication. Если клиент получит такой запрос, то в ответ отправит логин и пароль.